# Comm requires --nocheck-order on ~10.000 lines file?

Tags: comm

I want to use Comm to compare two log files. The files are around 1MB containing ~10.000 lines.
While testing with a small portion of a log `comm -1 -3 a.log b.log > diff.log` worked as expected.

However when testing with the full file I got the following message; `comm: file 2 is not in sorted order`.

When adding `--nocheck-order` to the command seems to work but why is this necessary? The man page doesn't really offer any insight. I just want to be sure my script outputs the correct data. I don't care in what order the logs are processed as long as it only outputs the lines that only exist in the second file.